# Monodroid ActionBarSherlock OnCreateOptionsMenu not called

Tags: actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android, menuitem

I have a main SherlockFragmentActivity which displays actionbarsherlock with only one menu item ("Done"). I am implementing this menu with a custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu_done"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkmark"
        android:title="Done"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_done_extended" />      
</menu>
```

And here the menu_done_extended.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Done"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkmark"
        android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_zando_theme_red"
        android:clickable="true" />  
  <View
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity, I override OnCreateOptionsMenu to display this menu:

```
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu( ActionBar_Sherlock.View.IMenu menu )
    {
        SupportMenuInflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.menu_done, menu );
        return true;
    }
```

And finally I override OnOptionsItemSelected (in main activity) to handle the menu click event.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected( ActionBar_Sherlock.View.IMenuItem item )
{
    switch( item.ItemId )
    {
        case Resource.Id.action_menu_done:
            {
               // do some job....
               return true;
            }
            break;
    }

    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
```

But when I click the menu item, OnOptionsItemSelected is never called. I indicate that my main activity hosts a fragment. But this fragment does not modify the main menu ( no override of OnCreateOptionsMenu  or OnOptionsItemSelected called from fragment). I have searched through the internet at stackoverflow but most of the problems and solutions i find are about menu item click events **from fragment** not being called. My case is actually that this event is not called **in main activity**. I cannot see what I am doing wrong.
Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

**EDIT**

In my OnCreateOptionsMenu, I added a menu like this (for test purpose):

```
menu.AddSubMenu( "Test" );
```

For this particular menu, which appears as a drop-down menu from a 3-dot menu at the top-right corner, OnOptionsItemSelected is called normally. So I think there might be something wrong on the xml that I inflate to display the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Since I am inflating a view to be used as a menu item, I must take care myself to provide a handler when menu is click. Here is what I have done:

```
                    SupportMenuInflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.menu_done, menu );

                    ActionBar_Sherlock.View.IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem( Resource.Id.action_menu_done );

                    LinearLayout layout = item.ActionView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.menu_container );

                    layout.Click +=new EventHandler(layout_Click);
```

Resource.Id.menu_container is a LinearLayout defined in my inflated view. It is clickable. So I provided a handler to its click event. This is the way I have solved my problem. Is there any other more elegant solution?